# XAMPP server Error

Tags: xampp

i have changed my OS to be able to install XAMPP because  i couldn't solve the setup errors by following the soultions which i searched for on stackoverflow and Youtube to solve this error

" Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!"

after changing my OS  and install XAMPP it was running without errors

then i installed some drivers and programs    the same error appear again in XAMPP

i changed the port  and it doesn't work
deactivate the UAC and again it dosen't work

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by another application using port 80

I know skype is known to cause this issue

Comment: but i didn't install skype till now

Comment: That means another program is using port 80.
I am not sure what program it could be